# Is there any way to application animation to the text of TextView only?

Tags: android, textview, android-animation

Currently I have the following code:

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(BridgesCloseActivity.this, R.anim.slide_in_up); 
myTextView.startAnimation(anim);
```

But this animation is applied to `TextView` background picture also, when I want to apply that to the text only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a way simpler method, but if everything else fails, you could try embedding a `TextView` and a `BitmapDrawable` in a `FrameLayout`, then apply the animation to the `TextView`.

Comment: Neguţ, I was thinking about such approach. But I need to change the size of BitmapDrawable in accordance with size of TextView (its size depends on the content).