# How to change size of BitmapDrawable in accordance with size of TextView?

Tags: android, bitmap, textview

I have `TextView` with background picture in my layout and would like to apply an animation to the text only. So, as I was advised in [the separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096734/is-there-any-way-to-application-animation-to-the-text-of-textview-only):

> you could try embedding a TextView and
>   a BitmapDrawable in a FrameLayout,
>   then apply the animation to the
>   TextView.

So, the question is what should be the layout that `BitmapDrawable` size would be changed in accordance with `TextView` size always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the drawable on the FrameLayout itself.
The FrameLayout will be the same size as the text, because of wrap_content, and so the background will be as well. The animation should only affect the drawing, not the actual layout, so this should still work when you animate it.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/your_background">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World" />
</FrameLayout>
```